# Neo4J server startup error after enabling the unmanaged extension configuration

Tags: java, neo4j, unmanaged, neo4j-embedded

I am using Neo4J community edition 2.3.0 on windows OS 10. Everything works well until I changed the configuration at **neo4j-server.properties** files as:

```
 org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged
```

The error at server startup is:

Starting Neo4j failed: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-5b85e832@73766070==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false

If I disable this change then server starts very well. I am trying to run the HelloWorld example for the unmanaged extension as given with the Neo4J tutorial and follow all the instructions.

The Java compiler used to build the Jar is 1.7 and I am working on STS tool.

An early response would be helpful.

The console log is as following

```
  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Successfully started database
2016-01-04 16:49:08.036+0530 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer] Starting HTTP on port 7474 (4 threads available)
2016-01-04 16:49:08.038+0530 INFO  [o.n.s.m.ThirdPartyJAXRSModule] Mounted    unmanaged extension [org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged] at [/examples/unmanaged]
2016-01-04 16:49:08.039+0530 INFO  [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer] Mounting static content at /webadmin
2016-01-04 16:49:08.040+0530 INFO  [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer] Mounting static content at /browser
Jan 04, 2016 4:49:09 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages: org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged
 Jan 04, 2016 4:49:09 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
   INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
   Jan 04, 2016 4:49:09 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
 2016-01-04 16:49:09.521+0530 ERROR [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer] Failed to start Neo Server on port 7474: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-148016ab@5234ecb5==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false
2016-01-04 16:49:09.522+0530 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
 2016-01-04 16:49:11.581+0530 INFO  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Successfully stopped database
```

Comment: can you paste the link of tutorial followed. Also ensure that you have plugin jar files in $NEO4J_HOME/plugin folder and your plugin jar does contain classes within the package = "org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged"

Comment: also share the contents of data/log/console.log

Comment: Hi Michael, The link for the tutorial is following: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html  and yes the JARs are in the plugin folder. And the package used is package org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged; The latest console log is following:

Comment: Added the server logs in the question itself.

Comment: hey i think in the pom you should ad "maven shade plugin". It is like an uber jar where every package is in so neo4j can find all packages.

Comment: @Riky how did you solve the error? Getting same here, org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-366c893e@8b2beeb7==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the .jar you are using does not have the required .jars

Try exporting the your jar as an executable jar (I did it from Eclipse) and check the option "Package required libraries into generated JAR"