# Starting Neo4j failed: unmanaged extensions

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to create an unmanaged extension using [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/). I'm currently using a Windows environment

Now, I followed everything and here is what my pom file looks now:

[POM](https://gist.github.com/vvavepacket/2569ab542fae6f2866be2e88c5edf9c4)

and here is my java class containing the unmanaged extension

[HelloWorldResource](https://gist.github.com/vvavepacket/0fc1d1a4151fe7c0909be96bc31cee83)

Now, I tried to run "`**mvn clean package**`", and it produced a jar file around 10MB which I then put into the plugins folder of my database.

When I start the server, the following error always appears:

> Starting Neo4j failed:
>   org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-49fd135@9bfd861c==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false

The log file is not useful as it doesn't show any exception that cause the it. Other people also reported the issue in stack overflow and appears to be a jar issue. What else could I have missed?

- [Neo4j fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128931/neo4j-server-fails-to-start-with-unmanaged-extension/36138300#36138300)
- [Neo4j fails in startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590179/neo4j-server-startup-error-after-enabling-the-unmanaged-extension-configuration)

PS: I'm using 3.0.3 Neo4j Community Edition.

Comment: Did you edit it into the server properties config?

Comment: Also the stack trace should be in the logs: for us I think it's `/usr/share/neo4j/logs/console.log` but it could vary. Depends where you installed Neo.

Comment: @two bits, yes i already added the necessary mapping to register the extension